# Spaces in file path not working with @ or \" (C#)

Tags: c#, powershell, path, filepath

I've tried to do my due diligence in searching before I post but I am having trouble with a space in a file path when launching a powershell script in a C# app. I have tried escaping quotes, using @ pretty much anywhere, single quotes. What am I missing here?

This is how I am defining the path:

```
public string importMusicLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Automation Toolbox\Scripts\Music_Import.ps1";
```

Then I launch a powershell process and point to the path, previously I had this working just fine without spaces when pointing to the path on my Desktop, but now that I want to put the application in Program Files the powershell window only detects the path up to the space.

```
private void LaunchPshell(string script) {
    string strCmdText = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), script);

    var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe", strCmdText);
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Like 5 minutes after I posted this I realized I don't need to be combining a directory, I was going to delete this but I can post the solution in case anyone else needs it. The general syntax for powershell to launch a script is `& 'C:\Program Files\Some Path'`:

```
public string importMusicLocation = @"& 'C:\Program Files\Automation Toolbox\Scripts\Music_Import.ps1'";
```

and

```
private void LaunchPshell(string script) {
    var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe", script);
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: What is your question? BTW, you approach `@"& 'C:\Program Files\Automation Toolbox\Scripts\Music_Import.ps1'"` will fail if file or folder have two or more adjacent spaces in its name.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting your path value with double quotes like

```
string importMusicLocation = @"""C:\Program Files\Automation Toolbox\Scripts\Music_Import.ps1""";
```

So, `PowerShell.exe` utility will receive the argument as quoted string and the spacing issue shouldn't arise

```
"C:\Program Files\Automation Toolbox\Scripts\Music_Import.ps1"
```

Comment: This is valid code, however it doesnt actually execute the script in powershell. Output: `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> "C:\Program Files\Automation Toolbox\Scripts\Music_Import.ps1"
C:\Program Files\Automation Toolbox\Scripts\Music_Import.ps1`

Comment: @nkasco prepend `& `